# Change the size of clusters based on the number of data points

Tags: python, plotly

I have a Pandas DataFrame where each row represents a data point, with two columns 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' to localize this point (WGS 84).
I'm trying to display clusters of these data points with Python, in order to make a map more or less like this one:
[image: Map wanted]

Two things are needed:

- the size of the clusters of data points should change according to the number of data points inside the clusters (see Figure above)
- the number of data points in each cluster should be written in the center of the corresponding cluster (see Figure above)

Moreover, the map doesn't have to be interactive (we don't need to be able to zoom in or out, nor do we need to move), because the goal is to include it in an academic paper.

With an official tutorial from Plotly ([here](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/)) I was able to display this map (it's obviously another data set with points only in the USA):
[image: Map displayed]

I used this code:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

px.set_mapbox_access_token(open(".mapbox_token").read())
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv"
)
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="lat", lon="long", size="cnt", zoom=3)
fig.update_traces(cluster=dict(enabled=True))
fig.show()
```

As you can see, the number of data points is indeed written in each circle, but the size of each circle doesn't change.

How can I change this? I don't need to do it in Plotly, any library is OK as long as it takes into account the two requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current offering seems to be to specify the size of the common circle that represents the cluster and the steps of size by zooming. See here for more [information](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scattermapbox/#scattermapbox-cluster). For still images, the reference [example](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#basic-example) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't necessarily require the use of the Plotly library, it was just an example. Whatever visualization package (Folium/Matplotlib/...) under Python that solves this problem is fine.

Comment: Then your question should be updated.